# Get textbox value in jquery but empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this code for getting value from text box. But I can't able to get value.

[image]

```js
$(function() {
  var get = $(".name").val();
  $('#test').click(function() {
    alert('Textbox:' + get);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" class="name">
<input type="submit" value="click" name="test" id="test">
```

Answer (score 2):

Get your value when you click on `#test`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#test').click(function() {
    var get = $('.name').val();
    alert('Textbox:' + get);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" class="name">
<input type="submit" value="click" name="test" id="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you were setting the `get` value at the beginning only, when the `input` box was empty. You have to update the value when you click on the submit button.

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('#test').click(function() {
    let get = $(".name").val();
    alert('Textbox:' + get);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" class="name">
<input type="submit" value="click" name="test" id="test">
```